# How to print AVL diagram in C++?

Tags: c++

How can I print a AVL in C++ so that the output is like:

```
   2 
  / \ 
 1   3
```

Besides , No matter how long the number is, it will display normally. And I used OOP.
There is my node:

```
template<typename T>
struct AVLTreeNode
{
    T data;
    AVLTreeNode<T>* LChild;
    AVLTreeNode<T>* RChild;
    int height;
    AVLTreeNode()
    {
        LChild = NULL;
        RChild = NULL;
    }
    AVLTreeNode(T data)
    {
        LChild = NULL;
        RChild = NULL;
        this->data = data;
    }
    AVLTreeNode(T d, AVLTreeNode<T>* L, AVLTreeNode<T>* R)
    {
        this->data = d;
        this->LChild = L;
        this->RChild = R;
    }
    AVLTreeNode(const AVLTreeNode<T>* N)
    {
        this->data = N->data;
        this->LChild = N->LChild;
        this->RChild = N->RChild;
    }
};
```

Comment: Printing an AVL tree is no different than printing a binary tree.  Search the internet for "C++ print binary tree", or more explicit: "C++ print AVL tree".

Comment: I recommend using a global variable to contain the "indentation" level.

Comment: OK, I have  completed Other AVL functions, just want to how to print AVL diagram,  I hope to watch my AVL how to work intuitively.

Comment: If you want other AVL functions node, pls call me

Comment: 1) Traverse the tree until you get to a leaf node.  While traversing, increment a level or indentation variable.  2) Print the quantity of spaces specified by the level or indentation variable, then print the data in the node.  3) Return to the parent node, decrement level or indentation variable.  4) printing of the link lines is left as an exercise for the OP.

Comment: I will do it later, Thank you

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.